# Spring data jpa - how to guarantee flush order?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a quite complex save process of Spring data JPA repos in one Transaction:

```java
mainRepo.save();
relatedRepo1.save();
relatedRepoOfRelatedRepo1.save();
...
```

And in the end I call (on `mainRepo`):

```
@Modifying
@Query("update mainEntity set finished = true where id = :id")
void setFinishedTrue(@Param("id") UUID id);
```

I want to guarantee that when `setFinishedTrue(id)` is called, all the related data are actually on the database because it will start an integration process that requires all needed data is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using standard settings JPA will flush data before executing queries. So you are fine.

If you want to be really really really sure you can add an explicit flush operation.
You can do this by either using the [`JpaRepository.flush`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#flush--) operation or by injecting the [`EntityManager` and call `flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush--) on it explicitly.